# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors rule

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In general, the eigenvalues of a real 3 by 3 matrix can be

(i) three distinct real numbers;

(ii) three real numbers with repetitions;

(iii) one real number and two conjugate non-real numbers;

Why cannot a 3x3 matrix have 2 real number eigenvalues?

Comment: As an aside, *complex* matrices *can* have exactly two real eigenvalues, for example with the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&i\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, because the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix is the determinant of that matrix. As your matrix has real entries, its determinant must also be real. This couldn't happen if you had two real eigenvalues and one non-real eigenvalue. (Or you could do the same thing with the sum of the eigenvalues and the trace.)

Answer (score 0):

Complex roots of real polynomials come in conjugate pairs.  Eigenvalues are roots of such a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalue equation $|M-\lambda I|=0$ gives, for a real $3\times 3$ matrix, the roots of a cubic polynomial with real coefficients. Polynomials with real coefficients have roots that are symmetric w.r.t. the real axis: if $\lambda$ is a root, so is $\bar{\lambda}$.

(you can have eigenvalues $a,a,b$ with $a,b$ both real. This falls under (ii))

Comment: So, according to the example you stated, $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ are also roots?

Comment: Yes, but since they are real, $\bar{a}=a$, $\bar{b}=b$

Comment: But you said if $\lambda$ is a root, so is $\bar{\lambda}$. Does it mean that if ${a}$  is a root, there should also be an $\bar{a}$ on the imaginary axis that is also a root?

Comment: Complex conjugation mirrors w.r.t. the real axis: $z=\alpha+\beta i$, $\bar{z}=\alpha-\beta i$. I do not understand why you think $\bar{a}$ should be on the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix of real numbers. If you had $AX=\lambda X$ where $\lambda$ is complex, and $X\ne 0$ is a $3d$ column vector, then you could conjugate everything to obtain $A X^* = \overline{\lambda}X^*$, and thereby conclude that $\lambda^*$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$. So the eigenvalues must travel in conjugate pairs for a real matrix $A$.